# How to calculate the area of the given circle segmentation highlighted in green?

Tags: geometry, circles

How to calculate the area of any irregular circle segmentation (highlighted in green)? Central angle is 90 degrees and the radiuses are 98/99 and 100/100 respectively.

[image]

Comment: how is the inner curve bounding the green region defined?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Area of half a circular segment of radius $r=\sqrt{c^2+a^2}=\sqrt{99^2+1}$, angle $\theta$ with $\tan\theta=c/a$, offset $a=1$, and half-chord length $c=99$ is the sector area $\frac{1}{2}r^2\theta$ minus the triangle's area $\frac{1}{2}ca$, that is, $$A=\frac{1}{2}(r^2\theta-ca)$$

[image]

Hence green shaded area is $\pi R^2/4-\frac{1}{2}(r^2\theta-ca)$ where $R=100$.

Answer: Approximately 255 sq.units.

Comment: Could you clarify where "r", "ca" and "c" (chord) are on the picture? thank you!

Comment: @Tamas The sector is the light blue shaded region. The angle $\theta$ should be measured in radians, so $\theta=\arctan(99)\approx1.56$.

Comment: Thank you very much!